# Convolutional network as a feature extractor

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network

I have to classify pictures as containing a certain object or not. Let's say I have to identify if there is a boat in the satellite picture. I only have 125 known boats in the dataset of interest. I believe this is not enough even using pretrained neural net.

So I've ad an idea of training my own convolutional neural net or retraining a pretrained one using a satellite images of boat dataset (10 000 images) on kaggle as a feature extractor. So I build a neural net that tries to recreate the flatten picture from the last flatten convolutionnal layer (my features).

Is there any tips or trick to make the neural net concentrate on the object rater then the backgroud? And is this known to fail or work?

Comment: You can first use an Object Detection model to localize boat(s) in the image. Then, crop this part of the image and send it to the classifier to determine the class of the boat.

Comment: Thank you, but if i don't have any bounding box.

Comment: @TanahelHuot-Roberge you could get a bounding box using Object Detection model. Simpliest OD model is KMeans clustering: https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_ml/py_kmeans/py_kmeans_opencv/py_kmeans_opencv.html. Model setmentates image to the background (water) and foreground (other stuff, ships). Regions with a lot of foreground pixels could be b-boxed easily. Then crop these refions as Schubham Panchal suggests.